# Get Friends' Open Graph Actions On Specific App

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to figure out how to see which friends of a user are also users of an Open Graph app, then display those friends' open graph actions on that specific app (i.e. news.reads).

So essentially to return friends actions on the app that are visible to the user.

The examples I've seen here show friends_actions permissions, yet news sites like Yahoo! and HuffPo are able to show on login friends who have read articles without requesting that permission (it's not listed in their auth dialog box).

How would you go about this?

Thanks!